# Using post handler inside a while loop

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use  `handler.postdelayed` inside a while(true) loop so every 5 seconds it will send a specific value using a button 
but when i press the button it just hang without any respond it doesn't crash neither send 
how can i use the post delayed inside the loop ?

```
 btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                while(true) {
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {


                                DatabaseReference childRoot = rootRoomName.push();
                                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                map.put("Name", username);
                                map.put("message", Response1);
                                childRoot.updateChildren(map);



                        }
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use periodic alarm manager instead. this code wont work

Comment: You can use a new Background Thread for this periodic update. If you want i will provide the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong. You are killing the app with a while(true) loop. Instead, you should call postDelayed from inside the run() method at the end, so that it schedules itself every time after its execution. Something like this:

```
handler = new Handler();

runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }
}

handler.post(runnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used an infinite while loop which will not terminate normally. I don't think you need while here, just configure handler as you need.

```
btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    DatabaseReference childRoot = rootRoomName.push();
                    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    map.put("Name", username);
                    map.put("message", Response1);
                    childRoot.updateChildren(map);
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
```